# Detect change of Orientation of SplitContainer at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to **detect at run time**, the change of `Orientation` of a `System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer`?

I could not find any event handler or a virtual function that I can override.

`Orientation` can be changed by the end user through a UI element (ex: a toggle button). But runtime might be an overkill. To simplify, while developing a UI class library in C#, a control in my library, which when placed in a `SplitContainer`, needs to respond to such an event in design mode to readjust its own layout and children. So I don't have the luxury of deriving from a `SplitContainer`.

Comment: How is the orientation changed?

Comment: @CodingYoshi, added some more info to the question. Hope it clarifies the situation.

Comment: why do you need to react to it at design time?

Comment: @CodingYoshi, sorry, my question was too cryptic. Further edited the question.

Comment: The user cannot change the orientation, only your code can do that.  There is no event for something you already know.  You could of course declare your own event and raise it in your button's Click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Source: Youtube</sub>

[C# SplitContainer Sample Code](https://youtu.be/17IhMeYGITc)

```cs
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(splitContainer1.Orientation==Orientation.Horizontal)
                splitContainer1.Orientation=Orientation.Vertical;
            else
                splitContainer1.Orientation=Orientation.Horizontal;

            splitContainer1.Focus();
        }
```